# Flutter error: AnimationController.stop() called after AnimationController.dispose()

Tags: android, flutter

I want to apply a custom theme to my app. So before creating the 'MaterialApp' widget I check the current theme in SharedPreferences. I used a Future Builder for that purpose.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  ThemeData myTheme;
  bool isDark;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isDark=false;
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getTheme(),
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if(isDark)
            myTheme=Constants.darkTheme;
          else
            myTheme=Constants.lightTheme;
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Sample app',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: myTheme,
            home: HomePage(),
          );
        }
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Sample app',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Loading')),),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  Future<bool> getTheme() async  {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance() ;
    isDark=sharedPreferences.getBool("isDark");
    if(isDark==null) {
      isDark=false;
      sharedPreferences.setBool("isDark", isDark);
    }
    return isDark;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine except this error. Also app does not crash.

```
E/flutter ( 5809): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 741 pos 7: '_ticker != null': AnimationController.stop() called after AnimationController.dispose()
E/flutter ( 5809): AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose.
E/flutter ( 5809): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter ( 5809): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter ( 5809): #2      AnimationController.stop (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:741:7)
E/flutter ( 5809): #3      AnimationController.repeat (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:637:5)
E/flutter ( 5809): #4      BallPulseIndicator.startAnim (package:loading/indicator/ball_pulse_indicator.dart:48:16)
E/flutter ( 5809): #5      BallPulseIndicator.startAnims.<anonymous closure> (package:loading/indicator/ball_pulse_indicator.dart:55:9)
E/flutter ( 5809): #6      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:326:39)
E/flutter ( 5809): #7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter ( 5809): #8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 5809): #9      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 5809): #10     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 5809): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 5809): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 5809): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
E/flutter ( 5809): #14     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter ( 5809): #15     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter ( 5809): #16     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter ( 5809): #17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I don't see any animation controllers in your code

Comment: I am not using any but still I am receiving this error. I don't know why. I did not receive them earlier when I did not implement the future builder.

Comment: Show your pubspec.yml please

Comment: `version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.6
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  loading: ^1.0.2
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  share: 0.6.5+4
  admob_flutter: ^1.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from [loading](https://pub.dev/packages/loading) plugin which is quite outdated. I would suggest [this](https://pub.dev/packages/loading_indicator) package instead.